# which one is better architecture for the WF4.0?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4

Our team is going to design a workflow solution for the log running processes. We have to maintain persistence and tracking and versioning for workflow. Workflow server needs to execute multiple workflow. We are using wf4.0. We are finding the best architecture for the workflow server. Following points are consideration in our mind.

1. Integration between WCF and wf and workflow stored in database.
         In this approach,  Client call a wcf service that  load a workflow xaml file from database and create object of WorkflowApplication with loaded workflow and execute this. In this approach only one endpoint exposed with the wcf service. Now wcf service responsibility to start a workflow using workflowapplication class.
2. Inbuilt integration of workflow service with wcf.
      In which a workflow is developed with  message activity and hosted with workflowservice host, client call directly by its endpoint.

Now I have to choose one approach from one of them. please suggest me to choose one or any other approach that is best suitable for log running workflow that also maintains persistence, tracking and versioning.

Comment: This is too subjective in its current form (the word "best" in the title is the tip of the iceberg).  If you can [edit] to turn this into a [good subjective question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) then please flag and ask for a moderator to review for reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposing the worklfow using the WCF integration is by far the easiest way to go. You can manage everything yourself but for the most part all you are doing is duplicating code that has already been written for you. If you like a challenge and are paid by the hour fine but if you want to get things done the inbuild solution is far more productive.

Comment: Hi "The problem solver", Thanks for your reply. My condition is here that business workflow is not defined yet. Our resposlibity is to develop a workflow service that can execute any type of business workflow with persistence and tracking. So suggest me to how to achieve it by inbuilt wcf wf workflow service host.

Comment: You can add persistence and tracking through the config file in a default behavior. That way all workflow services will pick it up. As for workflows, they are just XAMLX files, drop another on the IIS app folder and you have another workflow available. Of course the clients sill need to know about the operations and parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I have following questions in my mind:- 
1. Then for n no of workflow n no of workflow service need to be published (Hosted) on iis. 
2. 2. Client needs to know n no of wf service end point. 
3. Would you please suggest me any tutorial that can help me to execute multiple workflow using workflow service host.
Thanks again for your kind suggestion.

Comment: Hi Maurice regarding your comment "You can add persistence and tracking through the config file in a default behavior. That way all workflow services will pick it up". I am using devart and using oracle for presistence. Is your above statement is  supported by devart

Comment: Yes but you might have to make a custom WCF behavior extension to do so if one isn't provided.

Comment: thanks again..Any tutorial or document that can help us to achive above things... that will be really helpful.